# checking barcode value in Zbar SDK?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, barcode

I use Zbar SDK in iphone.is it possible to find out  invalid barcode through any delegate method in camera mode?for example if i take normal paper (not barcode) in camera mode, i have to display invalid barcode in camera mode after some time which is taken by ZBar SDK? I tried the  following  method,but tutorial says that it is for scaning photo library images.

```
- (void) readerControllerDidFailToRead: (ZBarReaderController*) reader
                             withRetry: (BOOL) retry.
```

Answer (score 0):

For camera mode, ZBar has no concept of failing after a specified time frame.  You will have to define it.

I would define a method something like this:

```
- (void)checkIfScanComplete {
   if(zbarWidgetController.decoding) {  // you may have to add a property for decoding
                                        // alternatively, check if captureSession == nil
      [zbarWidgetController cancelled]; // cancelled is part of CancelDelegate protocol
      // show your error message, but on be sure you do it on main thread
   }
}
```

Then call it after an arbitrary timeInterval like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkIfScanComplete) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourTimeInterval];
```

Comment: updated per your comment.  ZBar has no way of knowing when to consider a live scan "failed", so you must define it.